# Не работает библиотека requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 13, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path, is_binary
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cd import (
  File "C:\Users\rojq\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\cd.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .md import is_suspiciously_successive_range
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing md__mypyc: Не найдена указанная процедура.
```

main.py:

```
import requests
```

IDE: PyCharm

OS: Windows 10

Python: 3.12 (в venv 3.10)

Желаемая работа: Чтобы модуль импортировался без ошибок

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал более старые версии питона. Возможно, в самой новой есть ещё неисправленные баги.

Answer (score 0):

**Ошибка была связанна с новой версией Python 3.12!**

1. Для устранения необходимо установить Python 3.11 и перенести код.

2.Ждать пока выйдет стабильная версия Python / авторы модуля request исправят баг

Comment: Может, ошибка всё же связана с тем, что использовались _разные_ версии питона при разработке и в виртуальном окружении (venv)?  Поясните, как именно вы решили эту проблему.